# Foreach is only returning the first value of an array

Tags: php, arrays, class, methods, foreach

I don't understand why `foreach` is only returned the first value from the $even_values array:

Here is the value of $this->sequence array when I print readable on the fibonacci_sequence method:

```
Array ( [0] => 1 [1] => 2 [2] => 3 [3] => 5 [4] => 8 [5] => 13 [6] => 21 [7] => 34 [8] => 55 [9] => 89 )
```

So I'm trying to use the return array from `fibonacci_sequence` method on the `even_values` method.

Here is the full code:

```
class fibonacci {

    private $seq_limit;
    private $sequence = array(1,2);
    private $even_values = array();

    public function __construct(int $seq_limit){
    $this->seq_limit= $seq_limit;
    }

    
    public function fibonacci_sequence(){
       for ($i=0; $i<=$this->seq_limit-3; $i++) { 
        $this->sequence[] = $this->sequence[$i] + $this->sequence[$i+1];
       } 
       return $this->sequence;
       //print_r($this->sequence);
    }

    public function even_values(){
        foreach ($this->sequence as $value) {
            if ($value % 2 == 0) {
                $this->even_values[] = $value;
            }
        }
        //return $this->even_values;
       print_r($this->even_values);
    }


 }


 $fibonacci = new fibonacci(10);
 $fibonacci->even_values();
```

---

Comment: `$this->sequence` is an array with values 1 and 2. Only one of those two is even, so you only get one of those (2) added to `this->even_values`, which is output. What is your doubt?

Comment: Did you mean to call `fibonacci_sequence` at some point?

Answer (score 1):

You seem to have forgotten to invoke the `$fibonacci->fibonacci_sequence();` method to change the `$sequence` array, so do:

```
$fibonacci = new fibonacci(10);
$fibonacci->fibonacci_sequence();
$fibonacci->even_values();
```

[demo](https://3v4l.org/TsZ1X)

As suggested by @AbraCadaver, you can also call it from the constructor if it should always be populated:

```
public function __construct(int $seq_value)
{
    $this->seq_value = $seq_value;
    $this->fibonacci_sequence(); // <---------- ADD HERE
}
```

Comment: Yes, or call it from the constructor if it should always be populated.

Comment: Here is the value of $this->sequence array when I print readable on the fibonacci_sequence method. Array ( [0] => 1 [1] => 2 [2] => 3 [3] => 5 [4] => 8 [5] => 13 [6] => 21 [7] => 34 [8] => 55 [9] => 89 )

So I'm trying to use the return array from the fibonacci_sequence method on the even_values method.